# I am not able to get signature from java sever side(java servlet)

Tags: java, cloudinary

I take the signature on the server side(java servlet) to pass it to the html client. 
This is the code:

```
    Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(Cloudinary.asMap("cloud_name", "dvg8fiorp", "api_key", "742866863611915", "api_secret", "zF-GJqVyWjih_MqQGsYeSOVVmJ8"));
    String timestamp = (new Long(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L)).toString();
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map options = Cloudinary.emptyMap();
    boolean returnError = Cloudinary.asBoolean(options.get("return_error"), false);
    String apiKey = Cloudinary.asString(options.get("api_key"), cloudinary.getStringConfig("api_key"));
    if (apiKey == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must supply api_key");
    String apiSecret = Cloudinary.asString(options.get("api_secret"), cloudinary.getStringConfig("api_secret"));
    if (apiSecret == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must supply api_secret");
    params.put("callback", "http://localhost:8080/SimpleServlet/js/cloudinary_js/html/cloudinary_cors.html");
    params.put("timestamp", timestamp);
    String expected_signature = cloudinary.apiSignRequest(params, apiSecret);
```

Unfortunately, the last line of code fail and i don't know how get signature to pass it to html client

Answer (score 0):

First, note that your API Secret **Should not** be publicly revealed. I strongly advise that you generate a new pair or API key and secret from your **Security settings page** (https://cloudinary.com/console/settings/security).

Second, this actually generated the correct signature, I managed to have successful uploads with it.

In order to further understand the issue:

- What kind of an error response did you get?
- Please share your upload request code.

This is the server's response:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
com.cloudinary.Cloudinary.apiSignRequest(Cloudinary.java:93)
us.souther.simple.UploadServersideServlet
```

Comment: I solved my problem. the problem was due to commons-lang-2.1.jar. I put a later version in classpath, and I solved it.
Thank you so much for helping me
greetings
Roberto